# Find tag matlab gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface, tags

I am reading another programmer's Matlab GUI. It is really complicated. A lot of axes and bars and tables. When I look deeper into the .m file, I just cannot find the corresponding parts in the .fig layout. Is there any good way to do that? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [findall](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/findall.html) function:

> object_handles = findall(handle_list) returns the handles, including hidden handles, of all objects in the hierarchy under the objects identified in handle_list.

For instance, you might call findall(gcf, 'Type', 'Text') to find all text objects etc.

Also, there is the [findobj](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html):

> Locate graphics objects with specific properties